# Making controller code dry in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers having update action. Both the action have similar code and I am in a confusion how to remove duplication and make it dry. Code climate showing duplication problem in this one. Here are the details.

```
Controller 1:
respond_to do |format|
  if @business_profile.update(business_profiles_params)
    format.html { redirect_to settings_path, notice: t('setting_successful_message') }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to settings_path, alert: t('setting_failure_message')
  end
end
```

```
Controller 2:
respond_to do |format|
  if @contact.update(contact_params)
    format.html { redirect_to contacts_path, notice: t('contact_successful_message') }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to contacts_path, alert: t('contact_failure_message')
  end
end
```

so I want this similar content to be in one.

Comment: Try https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

Answer (score 1):

They are both missing `end`s to the `if` block and the first one probably has a typo in `stting_failure_message`. Both have missing curly right braces (`}`) in the `else` block. There may be more subtle issues.

Get the code running and passing controller tests before worrying about optimizations like extracting a shared method to call from the two controller update methods. For what it's worth, the current degree of duplication looks about right to me, in the local clarity of expression and independence in changes versus abstraction to de-duplicate code trade off. Look at this questions for a more general discussion of best practices in DRYing up controllers: [Best Practices for reusing code between controllers in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128450/best-practices-for-reusing-code-between-controllers-in-ruby-on-rails)

and the highest rated answer in this one re the cost/benefit of the extraction you are considering

[DRY Controllers in Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830558/dry-controllers-in-rails-3-2)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the *responders* gem, specifically FlashResponder (https://github.com/plataformatec/responders#flashresponder) and CollectionResponder (https://github.com/plataformatec/responders#collectionresponder) if you plan to respond with flash messages and redirect to the index action often.